# How to fetch data from PHP more simply, or how to filter the ones that I got?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm building a business listing website, and fetching all data from a database. The problem was that if I wrote a function for all the boxes uniformly, only the first one with the specified id would work. So I got the code below to do the work.

```
<?php
    if(is_array($fetchData)){      
    $sn=1;
    foreach($fetchData as $data){
?>

<div class="content">

    
<div id= <?php echo $data['id']??''; ?> class="business" style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);height: 100px;width: 400px;padding: 2px;overflow: hidden;">
    <container class="boxholder1">

    <div class="box1">
        <div id="titleLine">
            <p><img class="brandlogo" src="image/logo.png" alt=""</p>
            <p class="brandname"><?php echo $data['businessname']??''; ?></p>
        </div>
            )            
    <div id="datas"><div id="list">
        <p>County:<?php echo $data['county']??''; ?></p>
        <p>CITY: <?php echo $data['city']??''; ?></p>
        <p>Phone: <?php echo $data['phone']??''; ?></p>
        <p>EMAIL: <?php echo $data['email']??''; ?></p>
    </div>
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script>

        $("#<?php echo $data['id']??''; ?>").click(function(){
        if($("#<?php echo $data['id']??''; ?>").css('height') === "500px")
            $("#<?php echo $data['id']??''; ?>").css('height', '100px');
        else
            $("#<?php echo $data['id']??''; ?>").css('height', '500px');
        })
        $("#<?php echo $data['id']??''; ?>").click(function(){
        if($("#<?php echo $data['id']??''; ?>").css('width') === "800px")
            $("#<?php echo $data['id']??''; ?>").css('width', '400px');
        else
            $("#<?php echo $data['id']??''; ?>").css('width', '800px');
        })
        
    </script> 

    </div>
    <?php
    $sn++;}}else{ ?>
<?php
}?>
```

Surprisingly, it works perfectly for its purpose the boxes get displayed as I wanted, and the function works well too for each one of them. But now I want to filter the boxes by e.g location etc. and can't really get a solution for that.

I tried multiple ways for the filtering, but nothing really works, cause I can't reference all the boxes. That's why I need a simpler solution for displaying them or a working solution for the filtering. One of my attempts for filtering was something like this:

```
 $('#dropdowncounty').on('change', function(){
        $('.business').each(function(){
            var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
            var value = e.value;
            
            $('.business').each(function(){  
                if (county == $(value)) {
                    $(this).show();
                    
                } else if (county !== $(value)){
                    $(this).hide();
                    
                }  
    })});
```

I'd preferably keep the same concept with the expandable boxes.
Any idea is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code to something like this

```
<select id="dropdowncounty">
    <option></option>
    <option value="county1">county1</option>
    <option value="county2">county2</option>
</select>

<?php
    if(is_array($fetchData)){
        foreach($fetchData as $data){
?>
<div class="business" style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);height: 100px;width: 400px;padding: 2px;overflow: hidden;">
    <div>
        <p><img class="brandlogo" src="image/logo.png" alt=""></p>
        <p class="brandname"><?= $data['businessname'] ?? ''; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="county">County: <?= $data['county'] ?? ''; ?></p>
        <p class="city">City: <?= $data['city'] ?? ''; ?></p>
        <p class="phone">Phone: <?= $data['phone'] ?? ''; ?></p>
        <p class="email">Email: <?= $data['email'] ?? ''; ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }}else{ ?>

<?php } ?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>
    $(".business").click(function(){
        var height = $(this).css('height') === "500px" ? "100px" : "500px";
        var width  = $(this).css('width') === "800px" ? "400px" : "800px";

        $(this).css('height', height);
        $(this).css('width', width);
    });

    $('#dropdowncounty').on('change', function(){
        var county = $(this).val();

        if (county == '') {
            $('.business').show();
        } else {
            $('.business').hide(); // hide all
            $('.business .county').filter(':contains('+county+')').closest('.business').show(); // show only matched records
        }
    });
</script>
```

**DEMO**

```html
<select id="dropdowncounty">
    <option></option>
    <option value="county1">county1</option>
    <option value="county2">county2</option>
</select>

<div class="business" style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);height: 100px;width: 400px;padding: 2px;overflow: hidden;">
    <div>
        <p><img class="brandlogo" src="image/logo.png" alt=""></p>
        <p class="brandname">Business 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="county">County: county1</p>
        <p class="city">City: city</p>
        <p class="phone">Phone: phone</p>
        <p class="email">Email: email</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="business" style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);height: 100px;width: 400px;padding: 2px;overflow: hidden;">
    <div>
        <p><img class="brandlogo" src="image/logo.png" alt=""></p>
        <p class="brandname">Business 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="county">County: county2</p>
        <p class="city">City: city</p>
        <p class="phone">Phone: phone</p>
        <p class="email">Email: email</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>
    $(".business").click(function(){
        var height = $(this).css('height') === "500px" ? "100px" : "500px";
        var width  = $(this).css('width') === "800px" ? "400px" : "800px";

        $(this).css('height', height);
        $(this).css('width', width);
    });

    $('#dropdowncounty').on('change', function(){
        var county = $(this).val();

        if (county == '') {
            $('.business').show();
        } else {
            $('.business').hide(); // hide all
            $('.business .county').filter(':contains('+county+')').closest('.business').show(); // show only matched records
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There is never any benefit in duplicating an option's text as a `value` attribute declaration.  The redundant `value` declarations can be safely removed as needless HTML markup bloat.